# Can't see UIView after added to UIViewController in storyboard separately in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5

I have drag & drop `UIView` to `UIViewController` in storyboard in xcode 5, it's added but i can't see that `UIView` in storyboard. Any Solution?

Comment: Check if both the color of UIView and your view controllers self.view color are white only. It will be there but not distinguished from the other. Change the UIView color and see.

Comment: try this give any color of the view and run

Comment: Actually It works fine with .xib previous version of xcode but did not work in story board.

Comment: Change the color of view and then try

Comment: The views other than UIViewController's view couldn't be seen in older version of Xcode. Latest Xcode now shows them fine.